# Discussion about API Guide

Tags: discussion, recent-activity

I've created an [API guide](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1677/an-api-users-guide-for-free-and-open-data), similar to "[A Python guide for open data file formats](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1208/1511)".

I'd be happy to discuss how to shape meaningful answers, as well as the phrasing of the question. I look forward to you input, both as meta-discussion and also as answers in the thread!

**Q1**: Is it better to have multiple answers for each type of API or group of data (weather, finance, etc), or have all information in one answer like the Python thread?

Comment: I prefer to keep it simple in one post. Don't risk to be judged for rep hunting. I don't see the reason to multipost in the same question. Also, my suggestion is to reformat your question post. Make it simple and ask something without giving any answer on that section. Then, keep the whole answer in the answer section. I did the same mistake, but luckily, many users reminded me that this is a QnA site and you need a QUESTION and an ANSWER.

Comment: Will update. thanks for your feedback.